# How to install eAccelerator on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: php

How to install eAccelerator on Ubuntu Hardy?

I was following the instructions on this site: http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Improve_PHP_performance_with_eAccelerator_on_Ubuntu_8.04_%28Debian%29

but then got stuck at this command 'sudo phpize'. My servers says 'command not found'.

So what do I do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to install the php5-dev package in ubuntu to get the phpize command. It may not be in your path though so try running it from /usr/bin/.